# Managing dependences in a grails app (BuildConfig.groovy vs. dependencies.txt)

Tags: grails, config, dependency-management

I am still somewhat green to Grails. Seems to me that there are multiple locations where you can put dependent JARs, among them are BuildConfig.groovy and then there is dependencies.txt in the grails folder and then there can also be n number of 'lib' folders.

What is the difference between these? When use one over the other? Why can't Grails have one central place where all dependencies are kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method to manage your dependancies is through `BuildConfig.groovy` since it's uses repositories (maven for example) for making those resources available.

The reason for `grails-app/lib` being available for use is because there are cases where resources aren't kept in a repository for one reason or another and you need a way to include the resource directly with the application itself.

When in doubt always use `BuildConfig.groovy` unless you have a use case where you can't.

**Update**
The `dependencies.txt` file is simply a listing of the dependencies used by Grails and is not used to resolve them. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.5/guide/deployment.html).

> You can find a list of dependencies required by Grails in the
>   "dependencies.txt" file in the root directory of the unpacked
>   distribution.

Comment: Thanks, but what about dependencies.txt in the grails folder?

Comment: Updated the answer. That's just a listing of the core dependencies used by Grails. It's not used to resolve or control them.